# Is monotonicity condition not required in this short derivation?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For given density functions $p_1(x)$ and $p_0(x)$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$) the following equation is to be satisfied: $$(1-\epsilon_1)\{P_1[p_1/p_0>c] +cP_0[p_1/p_0\leq c]\}=1$$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $0<\epsilon_1<1$. To claim that there exists a unique solution to this problem he shows that the function

$$f(c)=P_1[p_1/p_0>c] +cP_0[p_1/p_0\leq c]$$

is continuous and monotone. The function $f(c)$ can be written as

$$f(c)=1-P_1[p_1/p_0\leq c] +cP_0[p_1/p_0\leq c]$$ $$=1+\int_{[p_1/p_0\leq c]}(c-p_1/p_0)p_0 \mbox{d} \mu$$

From here, he writes (with $[c<p_1/p_0\leq c+\Delta]\cup [p_1/p_0\leq c]=[p_1/p_0\leq c+\Delta] $)

$$f(c+\Delta)-f(c)=\int_{[c<p_1/p_0\leq c+\Delta]}(c+\Delta-p_1/p_0)p_0 \mbox{d}\mu+\Delta\int_{[p_1/p_0\leq c]}p_0\mbox{d}\mu$$

Where $\mu$ is some measure e.g., $\mu=P_0+P_1$. From here he concludes that $$0 \leq f(c+\Delta)-f(c)\leq \Delta$$
For any positive $\Delta$, therefore continuity and monotonicity follow. As a result the solution is unique.

> Don't we need $p_1/p_0$ to be strictly increasing (or decreasing) in order to claim the **continuity**? I also wonder the difference for the solution of the given equation when $p_1/p_0$ is constant for some $x$ and when it is never constant but also non-monotone.

If you could elaborate on this matter I will be very happy.

Thank you very much.

**The part below is already resolved**

**EDIT**: In his book about a very similar problem he says

> $\quad$Let $P_0$ and $P_1$, $P_0\ne P_1$, be two probability measures on the real line. Let $p_0$ and $p_1$ be their densities with respect to some measure $\mu(\text{e.g.},\mu=P_0+P_1)$, and assume that the likelihood ratio $p_1(x)/p_0(x)$ is almost surely (with respect to $\mu$) equal to a monotone function $c(x)$.

I am also confused here. What does being monotone with respect to some measure $\mu$ mean? is it possible that $p_1/p_0$ is not monotone but with respect to some measure it can be made monotone, it sounds really weird.

Comment: No, monotonicity has nothing to do with measures here, it is simply a monotone function on the real line. The measure comes in the "almost surely" part: The function is allowed to fail to be monotone on a set of $\mu$-measure zero.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I think the second part is clear now. Do you have any idea about the first part? My opinion is that if the function is monotone we have solutions to the equation for any possible $c$. If it is not monotone then we can have solutions but not for all $c$. Does it sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to show that $f$ is still continuous when $p_1/p_0$ is not strictly increasing but it is non-decreasing. That is when $p_1/p_0$ is constant at least for some intervals of $x$. For only whose regions where $p_1/p_0$ is constant it is easy to check that there is no discontinuity at $f$.

I am still not sure about the case where the function $f$ is not monotone at all.